# Widescreen monitor for graphic design and programming

Tags: monitors

I need a widescreen monitor for graphic design and programming.
The monitor will be connected to a ThinkPad X1 Yoga (gen. 2).
Specs:

- Flat, not curved
- IPS Panel
- Anti Glare Display
- QuadHD or 4K

What monitor can you recommend?

Comment: The graphics design element here is going to be the differentiator in terms of cost - what are your requirements in terms of DCI-P3/SRGB etc.? If you are looking for highly color accurate and calibrated displays it significantly restricts the screens you can look at. For some work this is absolutely key and generally speaking will double the price of a display